# Comprehensions In Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I just started to learn comprehensions and this made me a little bit confused:

```
list1=[2,5,7,8]
list2=[1,3,5,7]
list3=[3,5,7,13,17]

list={key:number for number in list1 if number %2==1 key="odd numbers"}
```

This produces a syntax error.

```
list={"odd numbers:":number for number in list1 if number %2==1}
```

And this produces a pair which contains the last catchen number item from the list1 which is 7.(Shouldn't it be like : odd numbers:5 , odd numbers:7 ?)

Comment: `list={"odd numbers:":number for number in list3 if number %2==1}` will give  `{'odd numbers': 17}`

Comment: I guess, you want to get a list of all odd numbers from the input list

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry yes it is 17 i'm editing it now

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you have a single '=', this should be two. In the second case you overwrite the first assignment because it has the same key. A key can only have one assignment, you could assign a list to it to get all of them instead.

Comment: Why should this be two ? I don't compare two different things i just assign " odd numbers" to the key variable.

Answer (score 0):

Each key in Python dict must be unique:

```
>>> list={("odd numbers:",number) for number in list3 if number %2==1}
>>> list
{('odd numbers:', 3), ('odd numbers:', 17), ('odd numbers:', 13), ('odd numbers:', 7), ('odd numbers:', 5)}
```

In your example you override each time value with same key in dict e.g.:

```
>>> odd_dict = {'odd numbers': 1}
>>> odd_dict
{'odd numbers': 1}
>>> odd_dict['odd numbers'] = 2
>>> odd_dict
{'odd numbers': 2}
```

Comment: Could I ask why we used comma ? Is there any specific reason for that ?

Comment: Do you mean in this example `("odd numbers:",number)`?

Comment: Yes , I meant this.

Answer (score 0):

Dict keys have to be unique. You are looking for *dict literal* with value being *list comprehension*, not *dict comprehension*.

Dict comprehension:

```
d1 = {"odd numbers": number for number in list1 if number %2==1}
```

Dict literal with list comprehension as a value:

```
d2 = {"odd numbers": [number for number in list1 if number %2==1]}
```

When using dict comprehension, same key is overwritten over and over again with new value. When using dict literal with list comprehension as a value, a *list* is assigned to mentioned key.

Comment: Thank you but in the first one I tried to do key="odd numbers" in order to assing "odd numbers" to the key variable but it gives a syntax error.Is there any way to do it [assigning a string to the variable] ?

Comment: @Elessar you need to show valid Python literal which is equal to your expected output. Your description is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> `list={"odd numbers:":number for number in list1 if number %2==1}` And
>   this produces a pair which contains the last catchen number item from
>   the list1 which is 7.(Shouldn't it be like : odd numbers:5 , odd
>   numbers:7 ?)

While making a dict comprehension keep in mind that dicts allow only unique keys, so you'll get `{'odd numbers': 7}` after iterating through the `list1`(getting the last odd number) appropriately.
To get a list of all odd numbers from the input list within a dict comprehension use the following approach:

```
list3=[3,5,7,13,17]
list = {"odd numbers":[number for number in list3 if number%2 == 1]}

print(list)
```

The output:

```
{'odd numbers': [3, 5, 7, 13, 17]}
```